# Ionic local notification m not getting pop up on screen when it reach

Tags: ionic-framework

Local notification not getting pop up  when it trigger,bt on slide down  from top m able to see notification.I want it should pop up every time when m getting notification in ionic 3

Comment: Improve your question please, you don't even say wich version of Ionic your're using

Comment: sry for that ..and thanks for suggestion

Comment: I'm able to use local notifications but without the $cordova wrapper. Use the cordova-plugin-local-notifications like: cordova.plugins.notification.local.on('click', fn);

Comment: Have you find any solution for that ?

Comment: no not yet i got solution